# How to make SSRS invoke a wcf service which is integrated with STS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, reporting-services

**Scenario:**
I have an website developed in angular js and  integrated with STS, while logging in I am presented with the STS login and after logging in with valid credentials - I am redirected to the main website. this far it is working cool.

To mention here, I have web api and wcf services which are hosted from within my website only, thus when the authentication is done at login - there is no issue in accessing the services as well (which are also protected by STS)

Finally we need to open SSRS reports from within the application using a report viewer control.

**Challenge**
The challenge we face here is that - due to the double hop

- from STS authenticated Web app -> SSRS(windows authenticated) -> back to Services(STS authenticated)

SSRS fails to access the services. Locally we have made it work by creating a separate web api project which exposes the service links and is without any authentication.

However we need to ensure that the reports can be accessed only by users who carry a valid claim generated by the identity provider.

Is there a way the SSRS can be made to be a RP with a trusted relationship with the STS?

Any help will be highly appreciated :).